# python | pexpect | ssh | no indication is received when the dest host is not reachable

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pexpect, pxssh

I'm using pexpect to connect with ssh to a distance host.
when the user or password are incorrect, I get an error
but when the dest host is not reachable (for example when I entered an invalid ip or if the host is down) I don't get any indication.
any idea why and what I should change in the command in order to get an indication in such case.

The source and dest machines are linux

this is the command I'm running

```
.../bin/python3 -c 'from pexpect import pxssh;import getpass;s = pxssh.pxssh();s.login("1.1.1.1", "user", "pass", auto_prompt_reset=False);s.sendline("touch /tmp/example.txt");s.prompt();'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting indication because the `pxssh` library dont provide feedback in your case. You would be better using the `socket` library to try to connect to the destination `host` before using `pxssh`

Here is how you could do it:

```
import socket
from pexpect import pxssh

def ssh_command(host, user, password, command):
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(2)
        s.connect((host, 22))
        s.close()
    except socket.error:
        print(f"Error: {host} is not reachable")
        return

    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    s.login(host, user, password, auto_prompt_reset=False)

    s.sendline(command)
    s.prompt()
    result = s.before.decode()

    s.logout()

    return result
```